# Why can't I access this struct through its pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, operators, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int element;

struct cell {
    element e;
    struct cell *p;
};
typedef struct cell* CELL;

int main() {
    CELL* p;
    p = (CELL*) malloc (sizeof(struct cell));
    p->e = 8;       /* This ain't working */
    *p.e = 8;       /* This doesn't help anything either */

    return 0;
}
```

I'm just getting started with `malloc` and I just made a pointer to a newly created `CELL`, which is a `struct`. Now I'm trying to fill it with some values, but I'm greeted by an unfriendly "request for member e" in something not a structure or union". I did make a pointer to a `struct` that contains a member called e, or at least that's what I think I did. Why does this fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
cel* p;
p = (CELL*) malloc (sizeof(struct cell));

*p.e = 8;
```

to

```
struct cell* p; // or CELL p;
p = (CELL) malloc (sizeof(struct cell));

(*p).e = 8; // . has higher precedence than *
```

Answer (score 9):

I think this nicely illustrates a rule of good C style - do not create typedefs that hide the fact that something is a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Since the typedef is a pointer type I think you want to cast it as a CELL not a CELL*.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the other fine answers by being explicit:

in your code, you define the `CELL` type to be "a pointer to a `struct cell`". Then you create yo local variable `p` to be a `CELL *`, i.e. "a pointer to a value of type `CELL`". In other words, a pointer to a pointer. That's one level too much. The "`->`" operator only follows one level of indirection, not two.

Answer (score 0):

I settled for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int element;

struct cell {
    element e;
    struct cell *p;
};
typedef struct cell* CELL;

int main() {
    CELL p;
    p = (CELL) malloc (sizeof(struct cell));
    p->e = 8;
    (*p).e = 8;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks everyone.